# Is it considered possible for women to compete with men professionally in team sports played with a ball other than baseball?

Tags: baseball, gender

In Little League play, a 13-year old girl, Mo'ne Davis, stunned the baseball world with her 70 mph fastball. Assuming that she "fills out" adequately during her adolescence, it is at least within the realm of possibility that she will develop a 90+ mph fastball with the requisite control to pitch in the majors. And if not her, perhaps another woman like her.

This situation came about because in baseball, you "play the ball, not the man." Assuming you have the required skills to handle the ball, you don't have to worry about being "overpowered" by a larger man.

Are there other sports other than baseball (or tennis, another "non-contact" sport) where there are female high schoolers (or college players) "coming up" that could plausibly play professionally against men? Or are the odds considered too long in contact sports?

Comment: I suspect this question is going to get into another "what's a sport?" discussion. Women already compete professionally against men in things like motor racing, snooker and chess.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I meant to ask about TEAM sports played with a ball (not one on one) and made that change in the question.And the last paragraph narrows it further to "contact" sports, not including "motor racing, snooker, and chess."

Comment: It might be better if you simply list the sports you consider acceptable answers - I answered assuming the American Big 5 but of course a list could include things like Cricket and Rugby if you wanted to be more international.

Comment: It's probably not considered a sport, but I bet women curlers would compete favorably against men.

Comment: `Melissa Mayeux, a shortstop on the French U-18 junior national team, became the first known female baseball player to be added to MLB's international registration list, which means she will be eligible to be signed by a Major League club on July 2.`.  [see article](http://m.mlb.com/news/article/132044338/melissa-mayeux-france-eligible-sign-mlb)

Answer (score 7):

The closest a woman has ever come to playing in a major North American sport is probably [Manon Rhéaume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manon_Rh%C3%A9aume), who was a goaltender for in the NHL's Tampa Bay Lightning system. She played in an NHL exhibition game and some professional minor league games. The trend seems to be that NHL goaltenders are getting bigger, which makes a woman playing in the NHL less likely, but this might still be the most likely opportunity in North American professional sports.

The knuckleballer [Eri Yoshida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eri_Yoshida) pitches in a Japanese (independent) minor league against men. A knuckleballer is probably the best opportunity for a woman to make it to Major League Baseball.

At the high school level, there are examples of girls winning against boys in wrestling matches. The weight classes are a huge assist at leveling the playing field there. Of course, there's not really a professional outlet there. I wonder how it would play out in boxing or MMA, although the public might not take to men fighting women.

Answer (score 2):

There is Korfball: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korfball

Mixed sport, but mainly played in the Netherlands and Belgium.

Comment: It is a requirement for them to have mixed teams.  Why would this be an answer?

Comment: Men and women compete in a team sport played with a ball, that their attendance is mandatory is not that important. The flow of the game allows it to be a mixed sport. Contact is limited to (almost) none, technique is more important than physical powers.

Comment: This is not an answer.  Then mixed doubles tennis would be an answer.  This has nothing to do with the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely team sport position (of the major professional league sports in the US, ie Hockey, Basketball, Baseball, American Football, and Soccer) for a woman to play in would be kicker in the NFL; this has come fairly close a few times, with several women playing in college football in that position.  Lauren Silbermann [tried out](http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/headlines/2013/03/female-kicker-trying-out-for-nfl/) in 2013 with the New York Jets, although she had no success (as she was injured in the tryout).  Several woman have played in college and semi-professional leagues, as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_female_American_football_players#College) notes.

Ultimately even there it will be difficult for a woman to play professionally, because the leg strength for kickoffs is critical - many statisticians believe the only repeatable success kickers have is in gaining a touchback on kickoff, with most other elements being fairly random.  This would be likely the weakness for a female kickers, so even a highly accurate kicker would be weaker on kickoffs and thus have a competitive disadvantage - but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question concerning the most popular sports in the US (Baseball, Basketball, Football, Hockey, and Soccer) it can largely be view by size and athletic ability.

This answer assumes the average woman to be smaller than the average man and the athletic abilities to correspond.  It also applies to only these 5 sports.

Of the sports listed, Basketball and Football are most reliant on size.  [This chart shows the average size of players from various sports](http://www.businessinsider.com/average-height-weight-nfl-nba-players-2014-8).

In those two sports, women would have basically no chance because of their limited size combined with the superior athletic ability of men.  Except for a possible long shot of kicker/punter as @Joe explains.

This leaves us with the other three sports:

1. In the NHL the only position that a woman would stand a chance physically is at goaltender.  @jerepierre has already touched on this.
2. In soccer the women could match up with the average size according to the business insider article, but the men would be superior in athletic abilities such as jumping and sprinting.
3. Women would have the best chance in the MLB as a knuckle ball or junk ball pitcher.  To do this they wouldn't necessarily have to be athletic or big.  They would need to perfect their craft of being a junk baller.  This would also obviously lead to other issues besides talent, but as John Kruk once said, [Lady, I'm not an athlete. I'm a professional baseball player.](http://www.baseball-reference.com/bullpen/John_Kruk)

Obviously sports that combine size and athletic ability would be an advantage to men.  This encapsulates most sports.  The possible niche being a sport where technique and practice can over take.  A good example is pitching in baseball.

---

Notes:

I stated in a comment on @Coach-D's post that I played NCAA baseball and we used to scrimmage the women basketball team at our school.  They had some players that were taller than our players, and they were more fundamentally sound than we were.  We would regularly beat them, and beat them easily.

The thought that Mo'ne Davis could compete in the MLB with a normal skill set (by which I mean a fastball and two off-speed pitches) is absurd.  Unless she developed a devastating knuckle ball she wouldn't stand a chance.  This is purely physiological, females mature earlier than males and most likely we saw the best pure athlete that she will ever be.  Don't get me wrong she could refine mechanics and control, but the likelihood she throws over 85 MPH ever is slim.  If she were able to do that, then she would join the club of thousands of males in the minor leagues and independent leagues that can do so also.

---

I don't not consider baseball a sport where you play the ball and not the man, as hitting versus a pitcher that throws in the 90's vs the 70's is a significant difference.  A sport that could fit into that is golf.  The ball lies the same no matter whom is playing it.  This leads to [Annika Sorenstam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annika_S%C3%B6renstam#Other_.283.29) who played with the men on the PGA tour and missed the cut in the Bank of America Colonial tournament.  During the same year she was able to win on the LPGA tour, leading me to believe that even for a woman to make the cut on the PGA tour would be a significant accomplishment.

Answer (score 0):

[Ultimate frisbee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_%28sport%29) supports co-ed play up to the highest levels of sport. Even at the WFDF World Championships, there is a separate mixed division where co-ed play occurs. While ultimate is technically a non-contact sport, incidental contact occurs all the time (and is mostly not penalized). Each team does have to field the same number of women, though, so this is not a perfect example of gender equality in sports.

Comment: The title limits the scope to only sports played with a ball, so Ultimate Frisbee wouldn't count.

Answer (score -2):

OK Mo'ne Davis is a horrible example.  Chances are she doesn't grow at all and her fastball hits 75 mph max.  Many 13 year old girls are fully grown, height-wise.  I have personally been around 2 very athletic girls that were very similar to her - one as an umpire and another I personally coached.  The girls at 13 are just more mature than boys of that age psychologically and developmentally.  Boys hit their growing spurt around 14-15.  So girls have two years in school that they might be faster or more talented in the strength/speed sports.  [Actually 4 years ago one of my boys played against a 12 year old girl in football that was laying kids out.  She is talented and will probably have multiple big-time college offers for 2-3 sports but you would laugh if she had football pads on now.  She's 5-8 120 pounds... almost the same size as when she played football]

I want a disclaimer to my answer in that I am pretty strict what I consider a sport.  Auto racing, board games, and strategy games are not sports to me.  I personally feel that bowling is not a sport (but a great game) and golf is right on the lowest fringe of sport.

Do women have a chance?  Well not anytime soon.  They just don't have the physical attributes that will help them, unless they start altering their physical attributes.  I remember my college (large D1 school) having the WNBA players stay in the dorms over the summer.  I was on the basketball practice team.  Was probably at the level of a DIII starter but nothing great.  We would play the WNBA girls daily.  My team would include 1-2 guys from practice squade and 2-3 "good" pickup players.

In their three weeks there the WNBA players never won a game.  They scratched, clawed, brought out their 6-7 big, it didn't matter.  They couldn't stop our first step or the power drive.   Number don't lie.  We won probably close to 100 games.  Most of these girls were stars at big D1 programs.  We didn't hold back at all (mainly because they started playing dirty in game one) but we weren't also "great" players.  I believe all of the girls we played were better basketball players than us - fundamentals, shooting, tactic, positioning, whatever - but the athletic disadvantage was too much to make up.

What sport are women closest to catching men?  I would think it would be the marathon.  Running that distance requires using your body's existing fat reserves.  Women have an advantage here.  They can possibly be lean and in race shape with more fat in their body.

Comment: Mo'ne's 5'4'', and 110 lbs. I could imagine her growing to 5'7" or 5'8" and 140 lbs. in three or four years. Using this trajectory, 90 mph is a "stretch" but not out of the question. And even 88 mph and "good command" might get her "drafted," but perhaps not all the way to the majors.And baseball is not a contact sport like basketball. Perhaps it is more like golf, "on the lowest fringe."

Comment: 5'8" would be a stretch.  75 mph might be a stretch.

Comment: 5'5" and 75 mph this year (2015). 5'6" and 80 mph by next year, 2016. After that, I don't know (just taking the overs).

Comment: @TomAu - that is not how it works with a young girl's progress.

Comment: I second your women's basketball example. During the fall the baseball team would play the women's basketball team in games and easily beat them. Their coaches tried to hold us back but pure athleticism won almost every time.

Comment: Really, marathon runners?  Sorry, there's some chance a physical 'freak' could be successful in something like baseball (particularly in a niche, like having a really amazing curveball - Mark Buehrle and others have managed with low 80s fastballs with other interesting pitches, or a knuckleball or similar), but marathon, absolutely no way.  The reference to 'fat reserves' doesn't make any sense at all (or find a link).  I don't entirely disagree with your answer (though I find the style abrasive and too informal for this site) but that last paragraph is flat-out wrong.

Comment: @Joe - http://www.smh.com.au/executive-style/fitness/catch-her-if-you-can-20110627-1gobc.html - Sorry it doesn't make any sense.  My life is training people and maybe I was assuming that people knew that fat reserves are used for high endurance activities.  Here is another link refuting my claim but also showing women climbing on men bigtime in marathons http://sciencebasedrunning.com/2011/06/women-are-unlikely-to-catch-men-in-the-marathon/

Comment: That first article is not talking about professional runners - but about recreational ones.  Look at marathon times - top woman runner would normally be in the 20s or 30s compared to top male runners, and even a world record woman would be something like 10th (I used 2012 Boston as my example, [here](http://www.marathonguide.com/results/browse.cfm?MIDD=15120416&Gen=M&Begin=1&End=100&Max=12588), though other marathons are typically similar).  Paula Radcliffe finished [15th](http://www.marathonguide.com/results/browse.cfm?MIDD=16030413&Gen=B&Begin=1&End=100&Max=32167) in London when she set

Comment: her record.  Women are climbing on men in times largely because male marathon times are probably reaching the minimum possible time (without some major change in physiology), but I don't see a woman being competitive for first place (which I assume as the bar for 'competing with') under any circumstances in marathons (though I guess that bar is more complicated given top 30 MLB Pitchers would be harder...)

Comment: @Joe - My point wasn't that women would catch men in the marathon.  It is just that the upper tier of athletes is really closer than any other sport that I can think of (and seems to be getting closer - where ever this might plateau).  Could a woman play minor league baseball with a knuckleball, maybe.  Could a woman be top 50 in the world at baseball... no.

Comment: I guess that's why the question was ball-specific; it's really sort of a different question.  Women do now currently run races with men, but they don't really have a chance to win - but Paula Radcliffe was a top-25 runner certainly in her prime.

Comment: @Joe - your example of kicker might seem the closest (because schools with no kickers let girls play) but there is NO chance.  I was 3rd string kicker high school and 4th-5th string in college.  We had a couple girls from the soccer team do some test kickoffs because this was the height of women kicking.  They could maybe get it to the 20 on kickoffs.  I was getting it to the 5-10 consistently and I sucked.  The gap between the worst kicker in the NFL and the woman with the biggest foot is very very WIDE.  I would bet on baseball pitcher before this.  Kicking is pure strength/explosion.

Comment: It's probably the closest as far as someone actually coming close to doing it professionally, despite that (given women have tried out!).  But I agree, it would be very difficult.

Comment: @Joe - But there has never been a team that has seriously thought about signing a women to kick professionally beyond trying to get some PR.  I mean a women could kick for an NFL team and make a few FGs and XPs.  So could I.  I don't think we should "count" something because it is a nice thing to do or for media hype.  The question should be answered based on merit of the athlete.

Comment: @TomAu - great to revisit past answers.   I wouldn't quit your day job!   5'5" and 75 mph huh?   She topped out at 5'4" and fastest pitch recorded was 71 mph.